# File bigger than RAM in google colab

Tags: python, numpy, google-colaboratory

I have a numpy file of 14 GB which I am using as training data for a Convolutional Neural Network. but the maximum RAM available in google colab under the free version is 12 GB. Is there any way by which I can fit this file on Colab?

Edit: I tried loading the file as an hdf5 as suggested by yann ziselman file but when I tried to fit it on the neural network, the RAM got overloaded and the colab crashed. I have pasted the code of fitting the hdf5 file here.  I would really appreciate if anyone could help me resolve this.

```
import h5py
files = h5py.File('/***/***/***/***/***/***/f_train.hdf5','r')

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras import models
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical

lab_all = to_categorical(lab_all,5)

lab_all.shape

cnn = models.Sequential()

cnn.add(Conv2D(filters=32,kernel_size=(3,3),padding='valid',activation='relu',input_shape=(300,300,1)))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(4,4)))
cnn.add(Conv2D(64,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu',padding='valid'))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3)))
cnn.add(Conv2D(128,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu',padding='valid'))
cnn.add(layers.Flatten())

cnn.add(Dense(32,activation='relu'))
cnn.add(Dense(64,activation='relu'))
cnn.add(Dense(5,activation='softmax'))

cnn.summary()

cnn.compile(optimizer='adam', 
loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics='accuracy')

cnn.fit(files['train'][...],lab_all)
```

Comment: what's the file format? can you save it as a hdf5?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Although I am now able to load the hdf5 file on colab, it crashes when I run the neural network. I would really appreciate it if you could tell me how to resolve this. If its not fitting on the CNN, then I am back to square one

Comment: I can't help you without more details. what error message do you get?

Comment: I do not get an error message, the RAM gets overloaded and then the colab crashes. I have pasted the code for clarity.

Comment: what's your batch size?

Comment: tensorflow has its advantages but I strongly suggest you start using pytorch instead. I personally find it much easier to debbug.

Comment: I have tried with batch sizes 10 and 100. The colab still crashes.
I am not familiar with pytorch

Comment: are you using a vm instance with access to a gpu?

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: i strongly suggest you follow [this guide](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/gpu.ipynb)